# Get transaction details including

Tags: transactions, getsignaturesforaddress

I was trying to extract as much data as possible about confirmed transactions, using the method `getTransactions(signatures[])`.

First I'm fetching all signatures by using the method `getSignaturesForAddress()`.
And then calling on them `getTransactions()` method.

Though, I do not see the required information. Like below:

1. token address
2. transaction amount (there is only pre/post balance)
3. which of the accounts is sending/receiving

Is there any other method which would provide the required info? Or maybe there are some libraries for fetching transaction data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking something like this

```
import { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";

const conn = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com/");

async function extractTransactionData(signatures: string[]) {
  
  const accounts: Map<string, number> = new Map();
  
  const transactions = await conn.getParsedTransactions(signatures);

  for (const transaction of transactions) {
    let { parsed } = transaction?.transaction.message.instructions[0];
    if(parsed.type === "transfer") {
      const { source, lamports, destination } = parsed.info;
      const sols = lamports * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
      console.log(`${source} sent ${sols} amount of SOL to ${destination}`);
    }
  }
}

await extractTransactionData([
"2o33gfsBkQN6QshgjECzBvHEjPx2ZPsb6YodJVX2BWiuYgJuXVjTC1bNoD7rbQUBTppVT3si9KaAXmuC4eyp8FnK",
"4kkKEdNN8UwfwcipTUGcrCmTGY13ak7QfcUrAEpzA8tjLDBSL4HQ4rgzubaUafXfEQkt67szywRb7ET4cKBeRnnz",
"5oaZrwwajXYMUn8EHbrnbedtDauwAhzWJUsMFpHXB8zeKSgu4zqBtfcBaQtPKbf2KMzwV74ZdramvwdHM4zhSTMJ"
]);
```